# How to preserve Labels when SPSS file (.sav) imported into pandas via rpy?

Tags: python, r, pandas, spss, rpy2

I'm looking to work on a SPSS files (.sav) using `pandas`. In the absence of the SPSS program, here's what a typical file looks like when converted to .csv:

[image]

On investigation into what the first two rows signify (I don't know SPSS), it seems that the first row contains the `Label`s, while the second row contains the `VarName`s.

[image]

When I bring the file into pandas thus:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com

def savtocsv(filename):
    w = com.robj.r('foreign::read.spss("%s", to.data.frame=TRUE)' % filename)
    w = com.convert_robj(w)
    return w
```

and then do a head(), the first row (Label) is missing:

[image]

How can labels be maintained?

- Ref: [Is there a Python module to open SPSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647006/is-there-a-python-module-to-open-spss-files)
- Python: 2.7.10
- Pandas: 0.17.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Labels in a `sav` file are stored in `variable.labels` attribute of the returning object from the [`read.spss`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.spss.html) function.

You can get the variable labels with the following:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com

def get_labels(filename):
    w = com.robj.r('attr(foreign::read.spss("%s"), "variable.labels")' % filename)
    w = com.convert_robj(w)
    return w
```

If you want to set the labels as the column names of your dataframe:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com

def savtocsv(filename):
    w = com.robj.r('foreign::read.spss("%s", to.data.frame=TRUE)' % filename)
    cols = list(com.robj.r("attr")(w, "variable.labels"))
    w = com.convert_robj(w)
    w.columns = cols
    return w
```

Comment: Great, that seems to do what I need, thanks. I guess I can then someone with pandas wedge these in to be the column headers, replacing the varName values. But is it possible do the conversion **and** include the labels in one go (one call to `com.robj.r()`), to save handing to do further manipulating in pandas?

Comment: It is possible to read the file once and get the attributes on the returning object but it will require another r call I think. Please see the update.